# The input data is not a complete block when decrypting using AES

Tags: c#, encryption

I am trying to encrypt data from oracle, then decrypt it using C#

so far, I managed to write a code that encrypts the data in both C# and Oracle, and I got matched results

I am trying to Decrypt the data in C# but I get the error :
"The Input data is not a complete block"

The Oracle Encryption :

```
SELECT DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt (RAWTOHEX ('Hello World!'),
                                       6 + 256 + 12288,
                                       RAWTOHEX ('4566456678997899'),
                                       RAWTOHEX ('1234123456785678')) /*AES128 = 6, CHAINCBC = 256, PAD ZERO = 12288*/
  FROM   DUAL;
/

SELECT   UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode('B6E88F68185584456FBF8FA799B10CA1'))
  FROM   DUAL;
```

The result after executing the 2nd query in Oracle is : tuiPaBhVhEVvv4+nmbEMoQ==

C# Class for Encryption/Decryption

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class AesTest {
        private const string AesIV = @"1234123456785678"; //@"d8zOcR9K9xqpl8Cd";//@"!QAZ2WSX#EDC4RFV";
        private const string AesKey = @"4566456678997899"; //@"NDsVwQwRbwbuYDcX2PRGwNewMediaCod"; //@"5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string src = "Hello World!";
            string x = AesTest.EncryptUsingCBC(src);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Text to Encrypt: " + src);
            System.Console.WriteLine("CSharp: " + x);
            string w = AesTest.DecryptUsingCBC(x);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Decrypt CSharp: " + w);
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static byte[] EncryptToBytesUsingCBC(string toEncrypt) {
            byte[] src = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
            byte[] dest = new byte[src.Length];
            using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()) {
                aes.BlockSize = 128;
                aes.KeySize = 128;
                aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV);
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey);
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                // encryption
                using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV)) {
                    return encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        public static string EncryptUsingCBC(string toEncrypt) {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptToBytesUsingCBC(toEncrypt));
        }

        public static byte[] DecryptToBytesUsingCBC(string toDecrypt)
        {
            byte[] src = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toDecrypt);
            byte[] dest = new byte[src.Length];
            using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aes.BlockSize = 128;
                aes.KeySize = 128;
                aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV);
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey);
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                // decryption
                using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
                {
                    byte[] decryptedText = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
                    return decryptedText;
                }
            }
        }
        public static string DecryptUsingCBC(string toDecrypt)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(DecryptToBytesUsingCBC(toDecrypt));
        }
    }
}
```

The result after running the program for encryption is : tuiPaBhVhEVvv4+nmbEMoQ==
but the decryption throws the exception

thanks in advance

Comment: You take a string containing arbitrary characters, convert those into bytes via UTF8 encoding, encrypt the bytes, and then convert those arbitrary bytes into a string using Base 64 encoding. If you want to reverse this process, you should be string -> Base 64 -> bytes -> decrypt -> bytes -> UTF8 -> string. But that's not what you're doing - your Base 64 and UTF 8 steps are in the wrong order.

Comment: This would have (potentially) been more obvious if you'd tried to write your "core" decryption routine to be more obviously the reverse of your encryption routine - I.e. the name and signature should be `public static string DecryptFromBytesUsingCBC(byte[] toDecrypt)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Damien, I have followed your tips and managed to solve the issue and finally got the code to work + got the same string i encrypted

here is the new code after doing the edits required

```
public static string DecryptToBytesUsingCBC(byte[] toDecrypt)
        {
            byte[] src = toDecrypt;
            byte[] dest = new byte[src.Length];
            using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aes.BlockSize = 128;
                aes.KeySize = 128;
                aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV);
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey);
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                // decryption
                using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
                {
                    byte[] decryptedText = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);

                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedText);
                }
            }
        }
        public static string DecryptUsingCBC(string toDecrypt)
        {

            return DecryptToBytesUsingCBC(Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt));
        }
```

Result after decryption is : Hello World!